# What is the difference between knn.score and accuracy metrics in KNN - SK learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am concerned about accuracy of my predicted vs test which completely make sense.

```
X_train , X_test, y_train ,y_test =train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'], random_state=0)      
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn.fit(X_train ,y_train)
y_pred= knn.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_pred,y_test)  # 97 % accuracy here I get accuracy score for pred/test
```

I tried same thing with knn.score here is the catch document says ***Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.***

```
knn.score(X_test,y_test)  # 97% accuracy
```

My question is why some one should care about this score because X_test ,y_test are the data which I split into train/test-- this is a given data which I am using for Supervised learning what is the point of having score here. Am I completely missing something In case If I check score it should give me 100% right

Comment: variables X_new and y_pred are not defined in your code. Can you fix that?

Comment: That was a mistake I updated it thank you

Comment: Thanx, that is what I thought. Does below answer your question then?

Comment: Thx for your help , I still have one doubt what is the purpose of the score function what is the realistic use case for that

Comment: I rewrote this a bit for (hopefully) clarification and added two use-cases were I have been concerned with this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *score* function is simply a utility function for a default metric to be used within some algorithms of scikit-learn (mostly the algorithms in the [model selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection) module, e.g. [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), or [cross_validate](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate)), if no other metric is specified. So for classification, this is typically accuracy and for regression mean squared error.

So it is the same, as it does exactly what you do in your code: it takes the passed matrix X (e.g. X_test in your case), calls *predict* and calls *accuracy_score*. Hence, no surprise that it is the same score. In fact, as scikit-learn is open source, you can just check that yourself [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/base.py#L324).

#### Edit:

So how does that concern you? Well, you can similarly use it in algorithms (e.g. if you build ensembles) or just to save a line of code as in your example above. If you were to build your on estimator this is something where you would have to think what is a reasonable default.

Comment: If it cleared it for you, would you accept the answer? Cheers.